# Replace comma with tab in Textmate

Tags: textmate

Is there a simple way to replace commas with tabs in Textmate, hopefully using the Edit > Find (command F) function?

I've tried /t and '/t' and haven't been able to find documentation about the correct syntax. Also, trying to avoid writing a Ruby script to do it, if possible.

Comment: RemoteSojourner's answer is perfect, but I'll go ahead and point out that a 'script' for this would be extremely easy too - Use "Text > Filter Through Command..." with the command `tr , '\t'`.  I find the "Filter Through Command..." operation extremely useful - with tools like awk and sed you can do some pretty nifty stuff with simple shell one-liners that look like line noise ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to insert a newline or tab character into either of the text fields, you can hold down option (⌥) while pressing the tab (⇥) or return (↩) key. This will insert a literal tab or newline character.

Comment: excellent, I knew I could avoid a script

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing alt+tab in the replace field or just copy paste tab character there.